# Generalized linear mixed model with (relatively) large dataset

Tags: r, mixed-model, large-data

I have some relatively larga data set (12 million obs.) and I wanted to fit a GLMM in `R` using the `glmer` function from the `lme4` package.

My data are requests (each observation is a single request) received by a bunch (30) of different operators in different regions (20), over the course of several years (10). So in my dataset I have some variables about the request (e.g. type, amount, number of previous requests by the same individual) and the date (year) the request was filed, the operator id, and in which region. The outcome is binary (success or failure).

I wanted to study how the request characteristics are associated with the chances of success, considering that the chances of success within regions and operators may be correlated (so I included random effect for those, and also the year).

I'm running something like this:

```
library(lme4)

fit <- glmer(
    success ~ type + amount + previous + (1|operator) + (1|region) + (1|year), 
    data = requests, 
    family = binomial)
```

But it never finishes!, when I use the whole dataset (12 million obs.).

I started developing the model playing around with a small sample (5,000 obs.) and then it is ok, but when I tried to run it with the whole dataset, it keeps running forever (one week and counting; this is in a not so powerful laptop, though; MacBook Air).

So, my question is whether it is actually feasible to fit such a model in a large dataset like mine.

I've read somewhere (I think it was in one of Gelman's book, but I'm not sure if this is his or he just quoted someone else) that when you have computational problems, it is usually because there is a problem with your model. But this model seems reasonable to my data and problem.

Any ideas on what can/should I do?

Comment: 12 million observations seems somewhat excessive for a GLMM. Is it really necessary to fit the model to all observations? You have 40000 values per operator and year. Couldn't you use a reasonable subset and use the rest of the observations for validation? If you must use all observations you could consider sacrificing exactness for speed and set `nAGQ = 0`.

Comment: thanks, yeah I guess I can use a subset. What I do not know is how big/small would be reasonable. To start building the model and see if things made sense, I used a very small sample (5k obs, so, ca. 0.04% of the data). And then I wanted to see how things look like with a larger sample. And I threw all the data in, but that clearly does not work (although I was surprised it kept running and did not fail for lack of memory).

Comment: Change to SAS,SAS can run that easily. I have run a dataset more than 200 million data records and several hundred variables.

Comment: @DeepNorth SAS being able to handle 200 milion records in PROC GLIMMIX? Or did you use another PROC, because this sounds very new to me that SAS would be able to handle that